# Why does typescript server in vscode overlooks null possibilty?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, null

I have a variable `db` that can be null:

```
import * as Sqlite3 from "better-sqlite3";

export let db: null | Sqlite3.Database = null;

export function initDb(filepath: string) {
  db = new Sqlite3(filepath);
}
```

However when hovering over it in vscode, it shows only Sqlite3.Database type, and when using it in an other file, it does not warn that `db` can be null, so I get runtime failure when it is null.

It seems basic Typescript usage, but I don't understand what is happening, what am I missing?

Here is my tsconfig.json for reference:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.test.js"]
}
```

Comment: You don't have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled. Do yourself a favour and just set `strict` to `true` it includes the null checks and others.

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you! If you post your answer I can accept it. I am surprised that Typescript does not check for null by default, I was too used to working in strict mode.

Comment: I'm also disappointed. I'd prefer the non-strictness to be an opt-out, not strictness an opt-in.